# How do I give the 2D cursor specific coordinates in 2.8?

Tags: uv-image-editor

In the UV Editing Workspace in Blender 2.8, many of the features present in Blender 2.79's Image Editing Panel no longer seem present.

How do I type in specific coordinates I want the 2D cursor to be? How do I return the 2D cursor to the origin? How do I snap the 2D cursor to a specific vertex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2D cursor to coordinates : you will find in the display drop down menu

[image]

The Snap to options you will find in the UV Context menu (right click) :

[image]

Comment: This helps a lot. I don't know why Shift + S lacks the same options that the context menu has. For those of us still using the superior right-click select paradigm, W opens the context menu.